# Not able to load s3 files into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load my files from S3 to snowflake using snow-pipe .
All integration looks correct and i was able to load earlier bit some thing is done by me not sure what but now its not working for me .
I am listing down all steps what i have done so far .

After creating  storage integration and updating IAM policy below steps is performed

1. Created table first test_table.
2. Created file format

```
    create or replace file format mys3csv 
    type = 'CSV' 
    field_delimiter = ',' 
    skip_header = 1;
```

3. Created Stage

```
    create or replace stage demo_db.public.my_s3_stage URL='s3://a4556-us-east-1-test/SNOWFLAKE/' 
    CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID='*************' AWS_SECRET_KEY='******************')
    file_format=mys3csv
    STORAGE_INTEGRATION='s3_int' ;
```

4. Created pipe

```
    create or replace pipe demo_db.public.mypipeaudit auto_ingest=true as
        copy into demo_db.public.test_table
        from @my_s3_stage 
        file_format=mys3csv;
```

I copied the SQS ARN and updated the S3 event for any create file .

But when i upload file in S3 it is not going through and select is not displaying records in Snowflake

Comment: Have you checked the "executionState" of the pipe?https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_pipe_status.html. And what about the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COPY_HISTORY where you can check if there was error within the COPY INTO? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html

Comment: pipe is running and another shows no record